# PHP mongoDB Driver MongoDB\Driver\Manager hangs

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, driver, freeze

I have a problem accessing a **mongoDB** database using the **PHP** driver.
When I locally run the following code:

```
<?php 
echo "Connecting";
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:28124");
echo "Connected";
?>
```

it works.
However, when I access this php file remotely from the browser, I only see "Connecting" and then the web page hangs with internal server error 500.

**I'm running with:**

> PHP 5.6.25 (cli)
>
> MongoDB: 1.1.8
>
> Apache: 2.2.22
>
> Any ideas?!?!?!?

Comment: Forgot to mention: there is no problem accessing the database remotely (say, using pymongo)

Comment: No clues in any of the log files (apache, php, mongo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of tracing the problem without logs.

Please check your default log, which should be in "/var/log/httpd/error_log" or "/var/log/apache2/error.log" (custom logs might not get all the info) and provide specifics.

If you are not getting anything from the logs, please retry after turning PHP logging on.

In php.ini(of apache dir):

Remove semicolon from in front of below lines

```
;display_errors
;display_startup_errors
;error_reporting
```

Set the values to

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Restart the server, run script, on error, check the logs again.

**Note:** Reset the php.ini to default values after you are done. Error logging adds significant overhead to execution.

Comment: Thank you for the tips for debugging this. I played around with installing different versions of apache/php and now it doesn't hang anymore (but I get a different error). I will post this as a separate question.